# How to pass array to if statement in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to be deducting money from a specific bank and loading it to wallet. i have two tables which has banks details and another money placed in each bank.
I have calculated totals of each bank and returned as an array.
below is the code

```
$banks_data = Bank::all();
    $banks_totals = [];

    foreach ($banks_data as $bank) {
        $totals = BankingTransactions::where('bank', $bank->id)->sum('amount');


        array_push($banks_totals,
            [
                'id' => $bank->id,
                'name' => $bank->name,
                'amount' => $totals,
                ]);
        }

//      retuns  array of bank and total money available
```

I want to check selected bank and check if the money is available. if its available i deduct and add to the wallet.
if not available no deductions.

here is code to load wallet

```
$petty_load = $request->all();
    
    PettyCash::create([
        'amount'=>$petty_load['amount'],
        'user_id'=>doe()->id,
        'bank_id'=>$petty_load['bank']
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Petty loaded succesfully',
        'alert' => 'success'
    ]);
```

i want to run the if statement to check the bank_id passed and amount. if the amount is available i load it to petty cash. if not returns error no enough money in the selected bank

Comment: What is your problem then?

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i want to run the if statement to check the bank_id passed and amount. if the amount is available i load it to petty cash. if not returns error no enough money

Comment: @FrancescoGallo check

Comment: @Ebi check now added more details

Comment: @Robert I've added to the question

Comment: Please write the statement in pseudo code